# Maximum Windows 8.1 CPU usage <= 30%

Tags: c++, windows

I'm writing a C++ application using Visual Studio 2013. The application iterates through an image doing some complicated analysis. To test code efficiency I am running the analysis (say) 100 times and seeing how long it takes. Then I modify the code, re-run the test and see if there is an improvement (or degradation) in performance.

Problem is that while I have a powerful 4-core i5 (i5-4200U @ 1.6 GHz to be specific) and plenty of RAM, the overall CPU utilisation never exceeds about 30%. My process never seems to get beyond about 29.5%. I've tried setting the priority class of my application to "High" (using SetProcessPriority) and this doesn't help. There is zero disk and network access, all in memory (and about 5GB of memory to spare).

Is this some secret Windows 8.1 setting (to preserve performance)? Can I change this programmatically or through some Control Panel applet?

Comment: Depending on how you obtain the 30% figure, it could be referring to a fraction of the entire box: 30% of a 4-core box is one core and a bit. Is your application designed to make use of multiple cores?

Comment: No, not specifically. I just ask Windows to "run through the analysis X times". I don't think the task is "atomic" and can be cleanly spread across CPUs. Hmm...is this relevant? I note from Task Manager that the CPU usage for each core is roughly the same.

Comment: It sounds like your application is not designed to use multiple cores, and is saturating a single core. To improve performance, you either need to make the single-threaded code more efficient, or find a way to make use of multiple cores.

Comment: @AlainD processes(or rather a single thread) doesn't spread themselves across cores. You need to code specifically to accomplish that - and it's rarely trivial.

Comment: @nos: You're right, making the code multi-threaded is not going to be trivial.  Curiously, each of my four cores is sitting at around 30% utilisation while running the test. My experience with previous versions of Windows is that one core would use a high percentage (close to 100%) and the other core(s) would chug along at close to 0%. This suggests that Windows 8.1 might be doing something like spreading CPU load across the cores for a single thread.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well how do you expect your application to use 100% cpu when it is (most likely) only running on one core because you aren't using threads?

30% is slightly above the usage for one core (25%) so it is almost certain you aren't using threads here.

Comment: In older versions of Windows single-threaded code, one core would tend to max out while the others chugged along close to 0%. Seems like Windows 8.1 is spreading the work for a single thread uniformly across all cores. If I set the process priority to "High", the individual core usages becomes less uniform, behaving more like previous versions of Windows in that one core usage goes right up. Overall, the processing time is not improved by setting the process priority to "High".

Comment: @AlainD One process will almost always max out one core, or alternate between which cores it is executing on (due to task switching). It cannot run on more than one core at once without threads. I'm not sure how you can be seeing this behavior to be honest.

Comment: I was surprised too. Instead of maxxing out one core as I expected, the levels on each core ran at around 30% each. I ran the application many times with minor modifications (always single-threaded) and it did the same thing every time. I'm thinking that it must be the OS (Windows 8.1) or (seems less likely) the code produced by the IDE (VS 2013) spreading the load.